# why use "Vue.prototype.$echarts = echarts"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, echarts

I google a lot but don't find the answer.here I am using vue .and I am confused why we use vue.protype.$echarts=echarts . is it related to the dom?

Comment: it's to make `$echarts` available in all components ... but is it `Vue.prototype.$echarts = echarts` or  `vue.protype.$echarts = echarts` - your title says one thing and the body says another

Comment: I don't think you need to modify prototype. simply set it to `vue` should be enough iirc.

Comment: well, but why bother bind it to `vue`? if you want you can always `import`

Comment: @appleapple This is a recipe how most Vue plugins work. This is a form of DI as a property can be overridden for one component or a hierarchy of them, something that is not possible when it's hardcoded to specific import. Works good with Vue test utils. Not necessarily a good practice because it pollutes Vue namespace and was established before the rise of ES modules but has its benefits.